# Can HDD be repaired?

Tags: hard-drive, repair

I've ASUS R558UF notebook and it's HDD failed twice in last 3 years. I got it replaced in warranty once, but now it's out of warranty. I was wondering whether it is possible to repair. It works sometimes, but stops randomly or mostly when I move laptop. I tried removing and reattaching it, checked all connections, everything looks fine, it makes a clicking sound before stopping. I was planning to buy a SSD instead now, I've heard that it is very durable. But it'll be good if I save money by getting it repaired. I'm not worried about my data I already have backup.

Comment: Good rule of thumb: never move a computer while the HDD is working.  Wait until the heads are parked or put it to sleep or power it down before moving.

Comment: While it possible to repair such HDD, I suggest you - don't spend time and money on that, if it start showing sign of failing, it will die sooner or later. Backup most important data or better clone hdd completely ASAP, so you would be able to restore OS if it still possible. SSD is much better if you use your pc on the go.

Comment: Hard drives are repaired only for the purposes of data recovery. The cost will almost always be considerably more than the cost of a new drive. And the repair will be considered temporary and not sufficiently reliable for continued use. Replace the drive, preferably with an SSD.

Answer (score 1):

SSDs are definitely more durable. Especially when you move around your laptop a lot ([refering to your other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1348310/do-you-think-how-we-carry-laptop-affects-its-internal-components)). SSDs have no moving parts inside of them and are therefore almost impossible to break simply by transporting them around - even while running.

As a plus, you get a lot more speed out of it. They aren't even that expensive anymore nowadays, so as long as you don't need a lot of storage I would recommend you to get an SSD. If you need more space, an external HDD is always an option.

Repairing an HDD (depending on the problem) is hard to impossible and in either way costs you as much as a brandnew SSD, especially when internal components are damaged. If all the connectors and the outside of the HDD generally looks good to you then it's most probably the internals that are damaged.

In almost all cases the only time you want to get your HDD repaired is when you have important data on it left that you need to access. Data recovery from physically broken HDDs can easily enter the four-figure dollar amount of repair costs.

Comment: So do you think it is worth considering to get it repaired or should I just buy a new SSD. My major work is done on rendering softwares if I think about it I don't need more than 200GB space. It can fullfill my demand of 4-5 softwares like AutoCAD, SketchUp, Rhino, Photoshop etc. Plus I can install 1 AAA title and 1-2 small games. And as for storing rest which includes pictures, movies, music and rest non important stuff, I've an external HDD for that.

Comment: An SSD would make a lot more sense for this kinda stuff, not just because it's more durable but also because of the speed. Since an SSD has no moving parts, it's very hard to impossible to brick it by transport, even while it's running.

Comment: I don't use laptop while travelling, I keep it in my bag and is turned off. but while travelling because I've to travel in crowded trains and I don't use a laptop bag, it gets pressed against crowd pretty hard. Its not just laptop my 3 mouse started giving me double click issue or lost the sensitivity of pressure on the click and that kept happening after every 2-3 month after buying new mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Physical hard disk damage means that the disk is either useless immediately or it's going to be useless soon, such that your data is in danger.  Copy your data off it ASAP and save whatever you can, and replace the disk (just as OP has done).

Something is causing OP's hard disks to fail at a high rate.  Perhaps the laptop has poor mounts so that the hard disk rattles too much, or perhaps the z-height of the mount is too small or too flexible so that ordinary moving and squeezing causes the spindle or platter to rub against the inside of the case.  Perhaps the electronics inside the hard disk (or the motherboard, or the power supply) are defective in a subtle way, causing the hard disk to fail early.  Perhaps the manufacturer keeps putting in old hard drives instead of new ones for warranty replacement.

In any case, replacing the hard disk with a modern SSD is a cheap and reliable fix.

Comment: If you look at OP's other question you can tell pretty easily that rather rough transportation while the HDD is running is most likely causing the early failures.